# Which of the run loop queues does each the new component lifecycle hooks run in?

Tags: ember.js

From Ember blog, these are the new component life cycle hooks.

> On first render (in order):
>
> - `didInitAttrs` runs after a component was created and passed attrs are guaranteed to be present. In Ember 1.13, the attributes will be available as this.get('attrName').
> - `didReceiveAttrs` runs after didInitAttrs, and it also runs on subsequent re-renders, which is useful for logic that is the same on all renders. It does not run when the component has been re-rendered from the inside.
> - `willRender` runs before the template is rendered. It runs when the template is updated for any reason (both initial and re-render, and regardless of whether the change was caused by an attrs change or re-render).
> - `didInsertElement` runs after the template has rendered and the element is in the DOM.
> - `didRender` runs after didInsertElement (it also runs on subsequent re-renders).
>
> On re-render (in order):
>
> - `didUpdateAttrs` runs when the attributes of a component have changed (but not when the component is re-rendered, via component.rerender, component.set, or changes in models or services used by the template).
> - `didReceiveAttrs`, same as above.
> - `willUpdate` runs when the component is re-rendering for any reason, including component.rerender(), component.set() or changes in models or services used by the template.
> - `willRender`, same as above
> - `didUpdate` runs after the template has re-rendered and the DOM is now up to date.
> - `didRender`, same as above.

These are the run loop queues:

> - The `sync` queue contains binding synchronization jobs
> - The `actions` queue is the general work queue and will typically contain scheduled tasks e.g. promises
> - The `routerTransitions` queue contains transition jobs in the router
> - The `render` queue contains jobs meant for rendering, these will typically update the DOM
> - The `afterRender` contains jobs meant to be run after all previously scheduled render tasks are complete. This is often good for 3rd-party DOM manipulation libraries, that should only be run after an entire tree of DOM has been updated
> - The `destroy` queue contains jobs to finish the teardown of objects other jobs have scheduled to destroy

Answer (score 0):

I've looked with help of browser development tools how Ember's run loop works and I can certainly say that:

`didInitAttrs` and `didReceiveAttrs` fire in `render` queue for 1 simple component:

```
Ember.component.extend()
```

and just `{{yield}}` as template.

Call in `render` queue:
[image: Call in <code>render</code> queue]